# replacing all open tags with a string

Tags: regex

Before somebody points me to that question, I know that one can't parse html with regex :) And this is not what I am trying to do.

What I need is:

Input: a string containing html.
Output: replace all **opening** tags

```
***<tag>
```

So if I get

```
<a><b><c></a></b></c>, I want

***<a>***<b>***<c></a></b></c>
```

as output.

I've tried something like:

```
(<[~/].+>)
```

and replace it with

```
***$1
```

But doesn't really seem to work the way I want it to. Any pointers?

**Clarification**: it's guaranteed that there are no self closing tags nor comments in the input.

Comment: And for self closing tags such as `<br />`? what about html comments? `<!--`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity it's guaranteed that there are no self closing tags nor comments in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have two problems: `^` is the character to exclude items from a character class, not `~`; and the `.+` is greedy, so will match as many characters as possible before the final `>`. Change it to:

```
(<[^/].+?>)
```

You can also probably drop the parentheses and replace with `$0` or `$&`, depending on the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `(<[^/].*?>)` and replace it with `***$1`